# write Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have some URLs like below :

http://srv1.Example.com/movie/99/09/06/The.True.Adventures.of.Wolfboy.2019.720p.asli.mkv.T8d89281498deef0.mkv?md5=d0c61a41d7d0095edc0210244561bb34&expires=1609025725

and

http://srv2.Example.com/movie/99/09/06/The.True.Adventures.of.Wolfboy.2019.720p.asli.mkv

Now I want select these Example.com URLs and index them. so need some regex for do it and export the path from it . I make regex, something like this :

http://[^/]+.Example.com/(?P[^?]*.(?:mp4|mkv))(.*)

Problem: When use above Regex, the path that export for me is like :

path=movie/99/09/06/The.True.Adventures.of.Wolfboy.2019.720p.asli.mkv.T8d89281498deef0.mkv

but I want the regex that support both URLs and export the path like :

path=movie/99/09/06/The.True.Adventures.of.Wolfboy.2019.720p.asli.mkv

I appreciate it, if help me to write a regex to export the path from the URL like :

path=movie/99/09/06/The.True.Adventures.of.Wolfboy.2019.720p.asli.mkv

Best Regards,

Hamed Haghshenas

Comment: The `.*` will always match as much as possible. Probably don't match anything at all after `mkv` if you don't want any trailing context., and probably switch `[^?]*` to `[^?]*?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
http:\/\/(?:[^\/]+\.)?Example\.com\/(?P<path>[^?]+?\.(?:mkv|mp4))
```

See the tests [here](https://regex101.com/r/cFZaKZ/2)

Comment: Thanks Dear I make some changes based on my environments and your Guides. Finally this solved my problem.
http://[^/]+\.Example\.com/(?P<path>[^?]+?\.(?:mkv|mp4))

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a regex, use a URL parsing module. Not only will the module do it correctly, but you don't have to read or debug the pattern. Once you have the object, you query it for the part you want.

[Mojo::URL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::URL) is such a thing:

```
use Mojo::URL;

my $url = '...';

my $path = Mojo::URL->new( $url )->path;
```

There's also [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI):

```
use URI;

my $path = URI->new( $url )->path
```

For the command line, I wrote [App::url](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::url). Behind the scenes it does the same thing, but I can then use sprintf-like formatting to get out the parts I want:

```
$ url '%P' http://www.example.com/a/b/c
/a/b/c
```